# Why I can ask question in MathOverflow and not here (MSE)?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions, mathoverflow, post-ban

Why I can ask question in MathOverflow and not here (MSE)?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You should be probably a bit more specific. Do you get some error message when you try to post a question on Math.SE?

Comment: Did you look at the pages I suggested you read [in comments to your last meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26566)?

Comment: "You have reached your question limit" is the message, that I have.

Comment: @Dattier If that is what you are seeing, then there is probably a bug. From what I can see, the reason you are blocked from asking questions should be the same as last time: your posted questions are sub-par (as judged by the community by votes/closing/deleting) and you are supposed to _improve_ your overall contributions (by editing your previous questions, or, possibly, by posting well-received answers). The lifting of the block will be automatic, and not even moderators can lift it early.

Comment: Thanks, but no bugg, that's the message which I have.

Comment: Can you please not post single sentence questions and force people to have to ask for clarification in the comments? You must have some idea of what context and other details you can provide. Last time you posted a question on Meta someone asked you for the error message. This time, someone asked you for the error message. Please in the future put the error message in your question.

Comment: https://i11.servimg.com/u/f11/19/69/75/42/mse10.png

Answer (score 12):

You cannot ask questions on Mathematics Stack Exchange because you are currently [question banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997). This ban is **automatic** and kicks in when some algorithm decides that your question contributions are of poor quality, and are not of positive value to the community.

In contrast, you are **not** question banned on MathOverflow.

Though both sites are part of the Stack Exchange network, they are quite independent (as are all Stack Exchange sites), and a question ban on one site does not carry over to another.

---

To get out of the question ban you should read and follow the advice given in the Help Center

- [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)

and also on Meta Stack Exchange

- [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997)

No, really. You'll want to follow the advice given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997).

Question bans do not time out, and moderators cannot lift them. The only way to get out of one is to improve the overall quality of your contributions to the site on which you have a question ban. Most importantly, you should improve your current questions through edits. New high quality *answers* may also lift the ban.

But I'd suggest you go through [your current questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=questions) and improve them.

Importantly, you should read [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) and also [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997). You will find advice for getting the ban lifted therein.

---

Last, but certainly not least, the following two pages are must reads.

- ## [***Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?***](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)
- ## [***What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?***](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997)

---

*Post Scriptum:* Make sure you visit the pages linked in [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26598).

Comment: It might also be a good idea to point out, that just because MathOverflow is a mathematics website, it does not mean that one should go and ask questions there if they are banned from asking questions here. Au contraire, if one is banned from asking question here, then one should probably *definitely* not ask questions on MathOverflow.

Comment: Very helpful and informative answer, arjifi,  with many explicit and clear  suggestions for a user facing such a ban, so my comment is rather irrelevant, but I did trip up a bit reading the first paragraph:  In particular  You write "This ban is **automatic** and kicks in when some algorithm decides that your question contributions [is something missing here?]. Also, the ban will only be lifted [is something missing here that you meant to say?]"  (Brackets mine).  Regardless, you've clearly and extensively dealt with the question.